# Is it possible to create dynamic inline bindings with Alpine.js?

Tags: javascript, css, alpine.js

I would like to create a dynamic `:class` or `:style` binding that uses data stored in an Alpine.js variable.

```html
<div x-data="{ divClass: 'inner', color: 'red' }">
  <div :class="${divClass}"
       :style="background-color: ${color}"></div>
</div>
```

In the example above, I would like the `divClass` variable to output a dynamic class `inner`, and the `color` to output a dynamic style `red` — is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of August 2021, it is not possible to do it directly. However, there are two possible solutions (mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/issues/213), in the Alpine.js repository).

### The hacky way

There is a simple hack you can use to achieve what you want, you simply need to wrap the values of the attributes in ***backticks***:

```html
<div x-data="{ divClass: 'inner', color: 'red' }">
  <div :class="`${divClass}`"
       :style="`background-color: ${color}`"></div>
</div>
```

### The libraries

There are two libraries that help wrap dynamic classes/styles in a nice-looking code. They are [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) and [stylenames](https://github.com/shatstack/stylenames). With them on board, the code could look something like this:

```html
<div x-data="{ divClass: 'inner', color: 'red' }">
  <div :class="classNames( divClass )"
       :style="styleNames({ backgroundColor: color })"></div>
</div>
```

###### *A biased disclaimer*

In my opinion, the first solution is better as it saves precious kB by not adding additional dependencies. However, you need to take into consideration that it's slightly less legible and potentially confusing for other developers.